# Why the wave function decays exponentially when it crosses the potential barrier?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

That may be an obvious question, but I would like a physical answer, not math.

Comment: can you clarify?  Do you expect it to *grow* exponentially?

Comment: but is this decay of the wave function related to the loss of energy when a particle crosses a potential barrier?? Would be that?

Comment: Would you care to elaborate a bit? Do you have any other expectation (like @ZeroTheHero said), why does it **not** make sense to you to decay exponentially (if this is the case), are you having problems connecting it to some other physical phenomenon, have you seen/read something that would suggest otherwise?

Comment: I don't know how to make this any clearer, but I'll try: why doesn't the wavefunction oscillate when it passes through the potential barrier and come back to oscilate after having passed through the barrier?

Comment: I wonder if it is stop oscilating because when it crosses the barrier, there is energy loss. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physics is similar to the physics of [evanescent waves](https://www.rp-photonics.com/evanescent_waves.html) in optics or more generally in EM propagation.

The idea is simpler to understand mathematically: in the classical forbidden region, the wave vector $k$ become imaginary: $k\to i\kappa$ with $\kappa$ real, so the solutions $e^{\pm i kx}$ go to exponentials $e^{\pm \kappa x}$.  The boundary conditions eliminate the growing exponential as the amplitude must eventually decay based on energy considerations.

Indeed, in optics the amplitude of the wave transmitted at a boundary similarly decays in certain conditions because no solutions of the sine or cosine form for the transmitted wave is compatible with the boundary conditions.  [This webpage](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electricity_and_Magnetism/Book%3A_Electromagnetics_II_(Ellingson)/05%3A_Wave_Reflection_and_Transmission/5.12%3A_Evanescent_Waves) gives additional mathematical details.

Evanescent waves also occur in [accoustics](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/evanescentwaves/evanescentwaves.html) although the physics is a little different since acoustic waves are longitudinal. Nevertheless, the physics here also involves reflection and transmission at a boundary.

Mathematically, if $E<V$ then the coefficient of $\psi$ on the right hand side of
$$
\psi^{\prime\prime}(x)=\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(V-E)\psi(x)
$$
is positive so the solution are exponentials rather than sines or cosines.  There is no “loss of energy” as the energy of the solution is fixed.

Roughly speaking, as in optics, the wave “doesn’t propagate” in the forbidden region.  In the optics case the lack of propagation of the wave implies lack of energy, but this explanation does not work well for QM as the energy is fixed (as mentioned above).

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation, I thought there was a more physical explanation (theory) and not so much related to mathematics (calculations).

Comment: Your explanation was very helpful and very clear. thanks A lot 

Answer (score 0):

Having an exponential decay just means that the probability of keep going *forward* into the classically forbidden region is the same at every point from there on; it does not remember how much it has already been attenuated from before. This is the nature of all attenuating homogeneous media in which waves, for example, electromagnetic waves, propagate; when the medium is homogeneous, the attenuation per unit length is the same everywhere, hence the exponential decay of the amplitude.